# "Root element is missing" error upon calling InitializeAsync on Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Layers.WmsLayer

Tags: arcgis-server

We are using ArcGIS and a call to InitializeAsync of an object of type Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Layers.WmsLayer gives error "Root element is missing". 
Stack trace is

at Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Layers.Layer.b__3(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Using the rest services API, "Current Version: 10.41", on a server.
Client is a WPF application.

Collegues of mine working on this project but from a different location don't have this error and the same code works fine for them. We suspect a network / credentials issue. A VPN is used.
I can see the services directory https://.../arcgis/rest/services/ using the Chrome browser, but get a 404 error using Edge.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A configuration (background for map) was missing for me. Now everything works fine.